# QGIS Intersect returns empty layer

Tags: qgis, intersection

I'm following these instructions from the FCC: https://transition.fcc.gov/form477/Geo/finding_census_blocks_in_qgis.pdf

Everything works just fine up until step #6, where the Intersect tool is used. I do everything just like the instructions, but when the Intersect tool finishes, it's just added an empty layer. I've hidden all the other layers, so it's not just getting buried underneath them or anything.

Any ideas as to what might be going wrong?

Comment: 12 pages is maybe too much to look at. Could edit your question an add an image of the polygon you are using to do the intersection (with no fill) on top of the blocks?

Comment: could be http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112056/qgis-intersection-problem?rq=1